# CSS background color is overruled by the background image

Tags: html, css

I have a webpage with an nice background image.

[image]

When I open an popup on that webpage is the background color set is css is interupted by the background image.

[image]

This is part of the CSS

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    background: url(../../images/background.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
/*  background: #e0e0e0;*/
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Tahoma, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #000000;
}

.pop_up {
    background: #f4f4f4;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    cursor: auto;
    border-width: 0px;
}
```

What should I add to the css to have in the complete popup the background color #f4f4f4 visible?

This popup is created by an script with an iframe in it.
I have tried to add the following code into the head of the popup file to try to overrule the css file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/style.css"></script>
<style type="text/css"> body { background: f4f4f4; } </style>
```

Comment: Are you ajaxing the popup in? My bet would be that there is an iframe with body tag in it, which is of course the same background as the main body.

Comment: Just a thought...try background: #f4f4f4 !important;

Comment: Thank you @Thangadurai, this solves the problem, please post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the below CSS, this will override other definitions

```
background: #f4f4f4 !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you have posted, looks like all you need to do is set the appropriate `z-index` value for your elements in CSS for the popup. Refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) for details on `z-index`.

In general, when applying a z-index value for overlapping contents, the element with the maximum z-index value is displayed on top, followed by the next max. value etc...